# Android Studio emulator won't connect to Xampp through the app, only through the browser

Tags: android, mysql, xampp

I am using Xampp to host a SQL database for an app I am working on, the database connects fine and I've tested it with Postman and can add data, but when I try to connect and post through the app, it doesn't connect, Ive tried using localhost, my ip address and 10.0.2.2, 10.0.2.2:80 and I'm at a loss, What am I missing?

The app has been tested on a different Xampp server and works, but on mine it will not.

Comment: DId you mean a browser on the emulator? If not then try.

Answer (score 0):

try to connect your phone and your development machine to same network and get ip v4 Address.
Then type it on your browser on your physicals phone if its redirect you to localhost then your app should work on your phone.
to get ipv4 on windows type `ipconfig` in cmd.